# Is it possible to set the return type of an abstract method to be the same as the class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I would like to set the return type of my abstract method to be the same as the class, not the type of the abstract class, but the same type as the inheriting class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the self-type pattern:

```
abstract class A<T extends A<T>> {
    abstract T foo();
}

class B extends A<B> {
    B foo() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thats exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: You can also just assign an instance of your subclass to a type of the abstract class.

Comment: You can do something likes this on the abstract class also
`T foo() { return (T)this; }` .

Comment: @EscĐiệp: *"You can do something likes this on the abstract class also T foo() { return (T)this; }"* ... You can, but it generates an unchecked cast warning which, for a purist approach, requires a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation which you can't do on a `return` statement.

Comment: @scottb
`@SuppressWarnings` can be used on `foo` method. And if you don't want to use on `foo` method, I think adding one more private method can be ok. Likes this `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") private T castThis() { return (T)this; }`. The `foo` method become `T foo() { /*do some other things*/ return castThis(); }`

Comment: For the record, OP asked about returning the same type, not necessarily `this`. I just used it for demonstration.

Comment: If It solved your problem. Then You should accept this answer @vexrav

Answer (score 0):

All three of these do exactly the same thing.

```java
public class TestAbstract {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      B b1 = new B();
      A a1 = b1.getMyClass();
      System.out.println(a1.getClass().getName());
      A a2 = b1.getItThisWay();
      System.out.println(a2.getClass().getName());
      A a3 = b1;
      System.out.println(a3.getClass().getName());
   }
}

abstract class A {
   abstract public A getMyClass();
}

class B extends A {
   public A getMyClass() {
      return this;
   }

   public A getItThisWay() {
      return this;
   }
}
```